# How to stop the execution of a Stored Procedure using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Lets say I have a stored procedure which has a simple IF block. If the performed check meets the criteria, then I want to stop the procedure from further execution.

What is the best way to do this?

Here is the code:

```
IF EXISTS (<Preform your Check>)
BEGIN
    // NEED TO STOP STORED PROCEDURE EXECUTION
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT ()...
END
```

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Just make a call to RETURN:

```
IF EXISTS (<some condition>)
BEGIN
    // NEED TO STOP STORED PROCEDURE EXECUTION
    RETURN
END
```

This will return the control back to the caller immediately - it skips everything else in the proc.

Comment: what to do in case that its an transaction ? it will say that "Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1"

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put a jump label at the end of the SP body, and issue a `GOTO` in the first `IF` statement. Alternatively, you can extend the first `BEGIN ... END` block to contain the entire rest of the SP body, and reverse the condition (`IF NOT EXISTS...`).